# How to I read the second line of the output of a command into a bash variable?

Tags: bash

I have a command that prints several lines and I do want to put the second line into a bash variable.

like `echo "AAA\nBBB"` and I want a bash command that would put `BBB` in a bash variable.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
var=$(echo -e "AAA\nBBB" | sed -n '2p')
```

With `awk`:

```
var=$(echo -e "AAA\nBBB" | awk 'NR==2')
```

Then simply, echo your variable:

```
echo "$var"
```

Answer (score 7):

Call `read` twice:

```
echo -e "AAA\nBBB" | { read line1 ; read line2 ; echo "$line2" ; }
```

Note that you need the `{}` so make sure both commands get the same input stream. Also, the variables aren't accessible outside the `{}`, so this does **not** work:

```
echo -e "AAA\nBBB" | { read line1 ; read line2 ; } ; echo "$line2"
```

Comment: To get the variable to exist outside of the block, use a method that does not involve a pipe: [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) `{ read line1; read line2; } < <(command)` or a [here-string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings) `output=$(command); { read line1; read line2; } <<< "$output"`

Comment: @glennjackman Please post the answer you give in your comment as it is the best given so far (all the other ones use an overkill `sed` or `awk` or `tail`/`head` combo).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sed`:

```
SecondLine=$(Your_command |sed -n 2p)
```

For example:

```
 echo -e "AAA\nBBBB" | sed -n 2p
```

You change the number according to the line you want to print.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by piping the output through head/tail -- `var=$(cmd | tail -n +2 | head -n 1)`

Answer (score 1):

Use an array with parameter expansion to avoid subshells:

```
str="AAA\nBBB"
arr=(${str//\\n/ })
var="${arr[1]}"
echo -e "$str"
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting a powerful built-in feature. Is the space between `/` and `}` really necessary?

Comment: Yes, without the space the substring has no valid replacement to define the separate array elements.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
var=$(echo -e 'AAA\nBBB' | sed -n 2p)
echo $var
BBB
```

Answer (score 0):

in a bash script:
Variable=`echo "AAA\nBBB" | awk "NR==2"`